# Packaging error when switching to arm64 (arm5 was OK)

Tags: ios8, arm64

I just plugged in a new iPhone 6, created a provisioning profile and then I launched the app I'm developing on the device. It compiled fine, but at linking stage it errored out with:

> ProcessProductPackaging
>
> ...
>
> error: class '(null)' of input object does not respond to either selector writeToFile:options:error: or writeToFile:atomically

I cannot find any information of what that is. I do not get any specific code reference to relate it to. Did anyone experience this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed an external library and related code I had and it's now working.

Comment: What library did you remove?

Comment: I think it was GPUImage

Answer (score 12):

Personally I was able to solve this issue by rebuilding the project a second time. I think I was only experiencing it after revoking and requesting a certificate.

Odd for it to jump at me and disappear though.

Comment: I got this error because, while archiving, I clicked on "register device" in xcode in my provisioning profile... I just archived again after and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I just restarted Xcode then the error was disappeared

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried turning the "Automatically managed signing" off and on again, then the issue disappeared. Note: rebuilding didn't help for me, cleaning either.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed some provisioning setting and then restarted the xcode afterwards the error was disappeared and archived and then uploaded successfully

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the project does the job for me. Actually I was making changes in capabilities while Xcode was building that makes build failed.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred after I made manual changes to the Xcode .entitlements and Info.plist files: I removed some entries. None of the above mentioned solution attempts worked for me. Every try to create an archive failed.

The solution was to go to Xcode's Capabilities section and switched everything on and off again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem specifically on an App Extension we used for Push Notifications, and I was using `Automatically manage signing` but it seems the App Groups in capabilities were failing, so I just had to make sure the App Groups were retrieved correctly and this fix it.

Also if you have .entitlements files, and you have App Groups there, make sure they are the same you are using in the capabilities configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted XCode and enabled and disabled to Automatically manage signing